# Handling a send button

Tags: python, django

```
@staff_member_required
@csrf_exempt
def send(request, request_id=None):
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    req= Request.objects.get(pk=request_id)
    request_folders = req.folder.all_files.all()
    context = []

    for doc in request_folders:
        if doc.meta.state == u'rejected':
            context.append(doc)

    if context:
        ctx = {'request': req}
        EmailFromTemplate('document-refusal', extra_context=ctx)\
            .send_to(req.customer.user)

    return JsonResponse({
         'success': True,
         'message': u'%s' % _('Message sent'),
         'redirect_to': reverse('messages:detail', args=[obj.pk]),
     })
```

Actually, this method could send a certain email with EmailFromTemplate. I pass this function inside an url.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, permission_required

from loanwolf.messaging.views import MessagingIndexView, send

app_name = 'messaging'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', login_required(
        MessagingIndexView.as_view()), name='index'),

    url(r'^send/(?P<request_id>[0-9]+)/$',
        send, name='send'),
]
```

So I use the function `send` inside a template .html. I have a button when once we click on it, it will send that message under certain condition. My problem is located if a guy click hundred times on that button, it will occur hundred of sending messages. How could I escape this issue? In fact, a solution of that would be handling in disactivating the button for 5mins each time it'll be used, but I don't even know how to do that. I would like to indicate the user that he'll be able to re-use the button in five minutes.

```
    <a href="#"
      title="{% trans "Send email - rejected file(s)" %}"
      class="btn btn-icon select-button"
      data-turbolinks="false"
      data-copy-to="{{ folder.pk }}"
      data-reload="true"
      data-url="{% url "messaging:send" request_id=object.pk %}">
      <i class="material-icons">assignment_late</i>
    </a>
```

Comment: Is the message body always the same? Reason I ask, is that it's easy to automate the URL. So pending how tech-savvy staff is, disabling the button will not stop the wicked.

Comment: @Melvyn Yes, it is. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Disable select button for 5 minute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.select-button').on("click",function(){
      $('.select-button').css('pointer-events', 'none');
      setTimeout(function(){ $('.select-button').css('pointer-events', 'auto'); }, 300000);
    })
</script>
```

Test with 3 seconds timeout:
https://jsfiddle.net/2hy4xxvt/

Comment: This snippet is good for your code, just add it inside html template

Comment: Yes, but how could I use it in my template?

Comment: Could you tell me at least how could I add a message : 'The button is desactivate for the next five minutes.'?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not at pc now..there are many ways. A simple js alert('message') or using jquery.

Comment: No, in using a jquery

Answer (score 0):

The architecture for doing this "disgruntled employee proof" is a little more involved.

The short version is that you only give out "can email" permissions once per x minutes. To do that, you need to generate tokens to store in the user session and track when she last obtained a token. Then modify the URL to allow for the token and your view to validate the token it against the token in the user session.

No valid token? No email. So if no token was given out, because she's in the cooldown corner, you can even render the button as disabled from the template.

As you can see it's a little involved, so I won't code the whole thing for you, but it helps you decide how tight you want the security and what it's going to cost to implement. If you run into specific issues trying to implement this, feel free to ask.

Comment: I don't want something complecated. Just desactivating the button for five minutes and inform the user the button is unusable for the the following five minutes. Could you do such thing in considering what I've done so far.

Comment: The answer @andrea has provided works. You just need to [add jquery](https://code.jquery.com/) - click one of the "minified" links to get the tag to insert in your template.

Comment: Could you tell me at least how could I add a message : 'The button is desactivate for the next five minutes.'?